# How to show 3 events on same date on calendar from web service in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, jtcalendar

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show multiple events on same date.I am using JTCalendar.

My code is like this

In ViewDidLoad

```
_calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
_calendarManager.delegate = self;
[self createMinAndMaxDate];
[_calendarManager setMenuView:_calendarMenuView];
[_calendarManager setContentView:_calendarContentView];
[_calendarManager setDate:_todayDate];
```

In viewWillAppear I code to change colour according to web service

```
[self serverconnectionScheduleAudit];
[self serverconnectionScheduleKPI];
[self serverconnectionScheduleMeeting];
#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    // Today
    if([_calendarManager.dateHelper date:[NSDate date] isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Selected date
    else if(_dateSelected && [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_dateSelected isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){

        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
           dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
           dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
           dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
           dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
            dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
            dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
    // Other month
    else if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }       
    }
    // Another day of the current month
    else{
        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    if([self haveEventForDay:dayView.date]){
        dayView.dotView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        dayView.dotView.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar didTouchDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    _dateSelected = dayView.date;
    dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
    [UIView transitionWithView:dayView
                      duration:.3
                       options:0
                    animations:^{
                        dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                        [_calendarManager reload];
                    } completion:nil];
    if(_calendarManager.settings.weekModeEnabled){
        return;
    }
    if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        if([_calendarContentView.date compare:dayView.date] == NSOrderedAscending){
            [_calendarContentView loadNextPageWithAnimation];
        }
        else{
            [_calendarContentView loadPreviousPageWithAnimation];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate - Page mangement
// Used to limit the date for the calendar, optional
- (BOOL)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar canDisplayPageWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    return [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:date isEqualOrAfter:_minDate andEqualOrBefore:_maxDate];
}
- (void)calendarDidLoadNextPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Next page loaded");
}
- (void)calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Previous page loaded");
}

#pragma mark - Fake data
- (void)createMinAndMaxDate
{
    _todayDate = [NSDate date];
    _minDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:-12];
    _maxDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:12];
}
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    if(!dateFormatter){
        dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
- (BOOL)haveEventForDay:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:date];

    if(_eventsByDate[key] && [_eventsByDate[key] count] > 0){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)funAddEvents:(NSArray *)arrDate
{
    _eventsByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    for(NSString *strDate in arrDate){

        NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformat setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];
        NSDate *myDate = [dateformat dateFromString:strDate];
        NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:myDate];

        if(!_eventsByDate[key]){
            _eventsByDate[key] = [NSMutableArray new];
        }

        [_eventsByDate[key] addObject:myDate];

    }
}
```

Connection Methods and Delegate

```
#pragma  mark - Schedule Audit Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleAudit{

    [customActivityIndicator startAnimating];

    int Auditid =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<AuditMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</AuditMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",Auditid];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/AuditMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit)
    {
        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
#pragma  mark - Schedule Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleKPI{

    int KPI =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<KPIMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</KPIMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",KPI];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/KPIMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

#pragma  mark - Schedule Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleMeeting{

    int KPI =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<MeetingMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</MeetingMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",KPI];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    // NSURLRequest *myNSURequestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/MeetingMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleAudit = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleAudit);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleAudit error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleAudit = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleAudit);
        NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
        NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Audits_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Audits_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleAudit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit =[responsedictScheduleAudit valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
            CheckString=@"0";

             [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleAudit];
        }
    }
    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleKPI = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleKPI);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleKPI error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleKPI = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleKPI);
        NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
        NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Kpi_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Kpi_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleKPI = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            StartDatearrayScheduleKPI =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            StartDatearrayScheduleKPI =[responsedictScheduleKPI valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
           CheckString=@"1";

        [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleKPI];
        }
    }
    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleMeeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleMeeting);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleMeeting error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleMeeting = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleMeeting);
        NSDictionary* AddressDict=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",AddressDict);
        NSDictionary *new =[AddressDict objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Meeting_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Meeting_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleMeeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting =[responsedictScheduleMeeting valueForKey:@"StartDate"];

            CheckString=@"2";

             [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleMeeting];
        }
    }
    NSMutableArray *arrDates=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:StartDatearrayScheduleKPI];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting];
    [self funAddEvents:arrDates];

    [customActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParsing Delegate

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FillBlocksNew"])
    {
        myDataClassObjScheduleAudit=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit);
    NSData *dataAudit = [myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleAudit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataAudit options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleAudit);

    myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI);
    NSData *dataKPI = [myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleKPI = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataKPI options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleKPI);

    myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting);
    NSData *dataMeeting = [myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleMeeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataMeeting options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleMeeting);
}
```

This is how I am showing

[image]

I need to show multiple events like this in the image 
[image]

I need to show 2,3 events on the same date on the JTCalendar form the web service and in the different colour.How to do this can anyone try like this.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Lion Are you there??

Comment: I have never work with `JTCalendar` so don't know how it works I have check demo of it but don't get idea from it to full fill your need.

Comment: @NiravD Any other calendar where I can do like this.

Comment: I have never work with any calendar app but let me find, if i will find i will post link here

Comment: @NiravD ok.....