# -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show data from web service to calendar.

My code is like this

```
-(void)funAddEvents:(NSArray *)arrDate
{   
    _eventsByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];


    for(int i=0;i<arrDate.count;i++)
    {

        NSString *datefromweb= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[arrDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]]; //Showing error on this like..
        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *randomDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        randomDate = [df dateFromString:datefromweb];

        NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:randomDate];
        //  NSLog(@"event date =%@",randomDate);

        if(!_eventsByDate[key])
        {
            _eventsByDate[key] = [NSMutableArray new];
        }

        [_eventsByDate[key] addObject:randomDate];
        // NSLog(@"afte event date %@",eventsByDate);
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `[arrDate objectAtIndex:i]` is a `NSString` object, not a `NSDictionary` object. Guessing? `NSString *datefromweb = [arrDate objectAtIndex:i];`.

Comment: You are having array of string not array of dictionary

Comment: can you print `arrDate`

Comment: @Larme Yes it is string object. So I can I show it.

Comment: @Larme I write code like this  NSString *datefromweb = [arrDate objectAtIndex:i];  and it shows error  setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

Comment: @Muju Can you show us console log for `arrDate`.

Comment: @NiravD It is String in array.

Comment: What error? Please, be clear. Give us the value of `arrDate` Or at least `[arrDate objectAtIndex:i]` It's unclear, what is your issue. My guess with your new error? The date format doesn't match? Is it because randomDate is nil? Which line?

Comment: @NiravD  ArrDate data =(
    "2017/03/27",
    "2017/03/27"
)

Comment: Now your issue is about the `dateFormat` of your `NSDateFormatter`. In which world `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` matches `2017/03/27`? When you do `[df dateFromString:datefromweb]` that's where lies your issue. Try with `yyyy/MM/dd` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrDate` is Array of `String` not Array of `Dictionary` also you are getting nil because of wrong `dateFormat`. Correct dateFormat for your string is `yyyy/MM/dd` and currently you are setting `dateFormat` to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` which is wrong, so changing `dateFormat` will solved your problem.

```
for(int i=0;i<arrDate.count;i++)
{

    NSString *datefromweb= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[arrDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]]; //Showing error on this like..
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
    NSDate *randomDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    randomDate = [df dateFromString:datefromweb];

    NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:randomDate];
    //  NSLog(@"event date =%@",randomDate);

    if(!_eventsByDate[key])
    {
        _eventsByDate[key] = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    [_eventsByDate[key] addObject:randomDate];
    // NSLog(@"afte event date %@",eventsByDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it solve by changing date format.

Comment: @Muju Welcome mate :)

Comment: can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090242/how-to-show-3-events-on-same-date-on-calendar-from-web-service-in-objective-c

Comment: @Muju Let me check if I have solution I will post it

Comment: Can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539307/how-to-post-string-with-special-character-and-thai-language-using-xml-parsing-in.

Comment: @Muju I have check your question not have solution for it

Comment: Not a problem I got solution. I just change code in unicoding.